# Enviar una variable que tengo de PHP por javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo este codigo:

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">//CARGAR MENSAJE
        //If user submits the form
        $("#submitmsg").click(function(){
            var q = $("<? $_POST['q'];?>").val();
            var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
            $.post("post.php", {text: clientmsg, q: q});                
            $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
            return false;
        });
    </script>
```

Como hago que me envie ese dato que esta en 'q' ?

Comment: usando `<? echo $_POST['q'];?>` no funciona?

Answer (score 3):

es muy sencillo, prueba asignarla con este código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var q = "<?php echo $_POST['q']; ?>";
</script>
```